# How to create a specific type of user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, controls, components

I am trying to create a winForms user control. But I want would like a User control that - when placed on the form -- doesn't take any form space. Instead, it lodges itself nicely below like OpenFileDialog does.

First, what kind of user-created thing is this? Is it still called a "user control"? If not, that may explain why all of my searches are in vain. Secondly, what object do I need to start with to create something like this?

A gentle shove in the right direction would be VERY appreciated.

Thanks.

--Jerry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controls that appear in the "component tray", like the Windows Forms Timer control, inherit from Component.

To create one with some automatic boilerplate code, right-click on a project and click Add... | Component

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're talking about creating a [Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I KNEW that... I feel an inch tall now.

I would love to retract the question and hide my stupidity, but I think I'll leave it up for everyone else who may be asking the same question and just need a gentle reminder, too.

Thanks for the whack on the noggin!!